# Как редактировать форму из админки?

Tags: php, битрикс

Сайт на битрикс и есть форма для связи, нужно сделать одно поле обязательным для ввода, т.е. тегу input добавить атрибут `required`. Но также нужно исправить атрибут `placeholder`, в котором прописано "не обязательно".
При поиске по всему коду сайта, "не обязательно" нигде не находится. Подскажите, как можно удалить этот атрибут `placeholder` из админки? С битрикс мало работал.
Версия битрикс: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь стрелкой выделил участок кода, выводящий нужное поле ввода с placeholder в форме:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
                <?foreach ($arResult["QUESTIONS"] as $FIELD_SID => $arQuestion):?>
                    <div class="input_div">
                        <?if(!empty($arResult["arDropDown"][$FIELD_SID])):?>
                            <?$name = "form_dropdown_" . $FIELD_SID?>
                            <select name="<?=$name?>">
                                <option value="" selected><?=$arQuestion["CAPTION"]?></option>

                                <?foreach($arResult["arAnswers"][$FIELD_SID] as $arAnswer):?>
                                    <option value="<?=$arAnswer["ID"]?>" <?if($arResult["arrVALUES"][$name] == $arAnswer["ID"]) echo ' selected';?>><?=$arAnswer["MESSAGE"]?></option>
                                <?endforeach;?>
                            </select>
                        <?elseif($arQuestion["STRUCTURE"][0]["FIELD_TYPE"] == "text"):?>
                            <input class="inputtext" type="text" name="form_text_<?=$arQuestion["STRUCTURE"][0]["ID"]?>" placeholder="<?=$arQuestion["CAPTION"]?>" value="<?=$arResult["arrVALUES"]["form_text_" . $arQuestion["STRUCTURE"][0]["ID"]]?>">
                        <?elseif($arQuestion["STRUCTURE"][0]["FIELD_TYPE"] == "email"):?>
                            <input class="inputtext" type="email" name="form_email_<?=$arQuestion["STRUCTURE"][0]["ID"]?>" placeholder="<?=$arQuestion["CAPTION"]?>" value="<?=$arResult["arrVALUES"]["form_text_" . $arQuestion["STRUCTURE"][0]["ID"]]?>">
                        <?elseif($arQuestion["STRUCTURE"][0]["FIELD_TYPE"] == "textarea"):?>
                            <textarea class="inputtextarea" placeholder="<?=$arQuestion["CAPTION"]?>" name="form_textarea_<?=$arQuestion["STRUCTURE"][0]["ID"]?>" ><?=$arResult["arrVALUES"]["form_textarea_" . $arQuestion["STRUCTURE"][0]["ID"]]?></textarea>
                        <?else:?>
                            <input type="text" name="form_text_<?=$arQuestion["STRUCTURE"][0]["ID"]?>" placeholder="<?=$arQuestion["CAPTION"]?>" value="<?=$arResult["arrValues"]["form_text_" . $arQuestion["STRUCTURE"][0]["ID"]]?>">
                        <?endif;?>
                    </div>
                <?endforeach;?>
```

В этом коде нужно сделать только одно поле `input type="text"` обязательным, но таких полей с типом `text` несколько, нужно только один конкретный. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервисы -> Веб-формы-> Настройка форм-> Выбираете вашу форму, переходите во вкладку [вопросы](http://joxi.ru/VrwzpNntKvV7xA), потом выбираете нужный вопрос. [Тут](http://joxi.ru/EA44aj1tDZPo3A) выставляете обязательный или нет. А далее во вкладке [ответ](http://joxi.ru/52aBJEytGZ9b0A) в первой строке ставите например пробел, а в поле параметр пишите `placeholder="Ваше значение"`